# Пользовательские функции языка С

Tags: c, функции

Пытался выполнить учебное задание, вроде все правильно написал, но после ввода массива программа вылетает с ошибкой "Прекращена работа ex.exe". В общем не понимаю в чем ошибка.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float sum1(int **b1, int m1, int a1)
{
int i1, j1;
float s1=0;
for(i1=0; i1<m1; i1++)
{
    for(j1=0; j1<a1; j1++)
    {
        if(b1[i1][j1]>0)
        {
        s1+=b1[i1][j1];
        }
    }
}
return s1;
}

int main()
{
int i, j, m, a;
float sum=0;

puts("Vvedite kolichestvo strok pervogo massiva");
scanf("%i", &m);
puts("Vvedite kolichestvo stolbcov pervogo massiva");
scanf("%i", &a);
int b[m][a];
puts("Vvedite elementi pervogo massiva");
for(i=0; i<m; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<a; j++)
    {
       scanf("%i", &b[m][a]);
    }
}
sum=sum1(b, m, a);
printf("%f\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: что за "b1" в функции sum1?

Comment: Ещё несоответствие типа параметра b в

     float sum1(int **b, int m1, int a1)

и

     sum=sum1(b, m, a);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

первая ошибка здесь (здесь и падало!)

```
scanf("%i", &b[m][a]);
```

должно быть

```
scanf("%i", &b[i][j]);
```

также мне не очень нравиться

```
int b[m][a];
```

Это, насколько я помню, будет нормально работать только в gcc, лучше явно выделять память через malloc.

Исправил, как я вижу это правильным

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float sum1(int *b1, int m1, int a1)
{
    int i1, j1;
    float s1=0;
    for(i1=0; i1<m1; i1++)
    {
        for(j1=0; j1<a1; j1++)
        {
            if(*(b1 + i1*a1+j1)>0)
            {
                s1+=*(b1 + i1*a1+j1);
            }
        }
    }
    return s1;
}

int main()
{
    int i, j, m, a;
    float sum=0;

    puts("Vvedite kolichestvo strok pervogo massiva");
    scanf("%i", &m);
    puts("Vvedite kolichestvo stolbcov pervogo massiva");
    scanf("%i", &a);
    int * b = (int*)malloc(a*m*sizeof(int));
    puts("Vvedite elementi pervogo massiva");
    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<a; j++)
        {
            scanf("%i", (b + i*a+j));
        }
    }
    sum=sum1(b, m, a);
    printf("%f\n", sum);
    free(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Мой эксперимент с 2-мя строками, 3-мя столбцами и числами 1 2 3 4 5 6
и исходной программой автора

привел к segmantation fault в строке 12 

    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    0x08048497 in sum1 (b1=0xbffff2b0, m1=2, a1=3) at ts.c:12
    ....
    12         if(b1[i1][j1]>0)
    ....
    (gdb) p b1[i1][j1]
    Cannot access memory at address 0x1
    (gdb) 

что, собственно, и ожидалось.

Comment: а как у Вас прошло ввод данных, где `scanf("%i", &b[m][a]);` ?

Comment: Действительно, сначала я запустил с scanf("%i", &b[m][a]); Соответственно в матрице была просто грязь. Но ввод прошел без эксцессов. Фатально стек не попортился.

Comment: Но это просто повезло. Вполне могло и порчей стека обойтись. Техника дошла то того, что компиляторы заводят массивы на пару байт больше, что бы обойти (и задетектить) подобные баги. Конечно, дальше есть также баги, но у меня до них даже исполнение не дошло:)

Comment: Или не повезло, это как смотреть на такие вещи. По мне, так чем раньше завалится, тем лучше.

Просто по опыту, порча стека (а массив b[m][a] выделяется в стеке) реже кладет программу, чем доступ по некорректному указателю.

Comment: все зависит от того, как компилятор код расставит.

Answer (score 3):

У Вас программа в sum1 падает. На самом деле тип b в ней и ее вызов надо описать по другому.

```
float sum1 (int *b, int rows, int cols)
{
   int i; float s = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < rows*cols; i++)
     if (b[i] > 0)
       s += b[i];
   return s;
}

....
sum = sum1(&b[0][0], m, a);
....
```

Вообще же, если хотите обратится в sum1() к b[i][j], то формула такая

```
b[i*cols + j]  // i-я строка, j-ый столбец
```

Вы же описывате в sum1 аргумент b как массив указателей. Соответственно компилятор делает код, который берет ячейку b[i1], рассматривает ее как указатель и адресуется к ячейке [j1] от этого указателя.

В общем сильно мимо желаемого Вами места.

---

А что такое *пользовательские функции* я не понял.

Comment: @avp: пользовательские функции -- видимо, не из библиотечные, те, которые самому надо определять :-)